# Exact equations: how do I get from a potential function to a solution?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am able to get the potential function when solving an exact differential equation, but I don't know how to get to my solutions using

$$\Psi \left (x, y \right )=c$$

$$d\Psi \left (x, y \right )=0$$

Have I just forgotten something from calc3?

For an example:

$$y' = \frac{y^2-2t}{e^y-2ty}; y(1) = 0$$

gives potential function

$$\Psi (t, y) = {y^2}t-e^y-t^2$$ (Should there be a +c on the end?)

Once I have that how do I get a general solution/plug in initial conditions?

Answer (score 1):

When you've finally found the function $\Psi(x,y)$ such that $d\Psi = M(x,y) dx + N(x,y) dy$, the general solution can be written as function level sets $\Psi(x,y) = C$ (for all values of $C$ that can take function $\Psi(x,y)$). If you have to solve IVP $y(x_0) = y_0$ then you just plug these values into $\Psi(x,y)$ and obtain $C_0 = \Psi(x_0, y_0)$. So, the set of points $\Psi(x, y) = C_0$ is an integral curve which passes through point $(x_0, y_0)$. In some cases you can find an explicit function $y = f(x)$ from $\Psi(x,y) = C_0$, but not always. For this type of equations it is acceptable to have solution written in form of implicit function $\Psi(x,y) = C$.